# Given $E=\mathbb{R}^3$, let $f$ be an endomorphism of $E$ defined by the matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$ on the canonic basis. Let $v,w$ be two eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given $E=\mathbb{R}^3$, let $f$ be an endomorphism of $E$ defined by the matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$ on the canonic basis. Let $v,w$ be two linearly independent eigenvectors.

1. Give a plane that is invariant to $f$.
2. Let $f$ be diagonalizable with a simple eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and a double eigenvalue $\lambda_2$. Show that $f$ admits an infinite number of stable planes.

   ---

For 1, is the plane defined by $v,w$ the one invariant to $f$? Because $f(av+bw)=af(v)+bf(w)= \lambda_1 av+ \lambda_2 bw$. Given that the vectors are independent, they map the whole plane on which they lay.

For 2, the eigenvectors $v,w,u$ are independent (because $f$ is diagonalizable) . $f(au+bv+cw)= \lambda_1 au + \lambda_2(bv+cw)$, but how do i go on from here? Similarly to 1. i know that $bv+cw$ map a plane so the same plane is mapped by $\lambda_2(bv+cw)$. Do i have to use the fact that $a$ is arbitrary somehow?

Comment: 1) Correct: You can generalize your proof to show that any subspace generated by eigen-vectors is invariant [by the way you do not need to show they map the whole plane]

Comment: 2) Hint: How many eigenvectors can you find for a multiple eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to (1) is correct, and for two you're almost there: take $\;v_1\;$ and eigenvector for the simple eigenvalue $\;\lambda_1\;$ , and take $\;w:=av_2+bv_3\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;v_2,v_3\;$ two linearly ind. eigenvectors for the other, the double, eigenvalue $\;\lambda_2\;$ , then

$$f(\alpha v_1+\beta w)=\alpha f(v_1)+\beta f(w)=\alpha\lambda_1 v_1+\beta\lambda_2(av_2+bv_3)\in\text{Span}\,\{v_1\,,\,av_2+bv_3\}$$

Finally, check that

$$\text{Span}\,\{v_1\,,\,av_2+bv_3\}=\text{Span}\,\{v_1\,,\,a'v_2+b'v_3\}\iff av_2+bv_3=k(a'v_2+b'v_3)\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb R$$

$$\iff \begin{cases}a=ka'\\{}\\\;\;\;\text{and also}\\{}\\b=kb'\end{cases}\iff\frac a{a'}=\frac b{b'}\;$$

and since we're working over an infinite field the above quotients have an infinite number of possibilities to *not to be true*...

**Note:** If you know about *generalized eigenvectors* the second part above can be seriously shortened...